# Placing conditional div tags in React JS render

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to put some div tags in the render block based on some conditions. I'm iterating through an array and I want to split the rendered data into blocks of 3, i.e.

```
array.map((data, index) => {
   if(index % 3 === 0) {
      <div class="topLayer">
      <div class="container">
   }
   <div><p>Displaying index {i} , data is: {array[i]}</p></div>
   if(index % 3 === 0) {
      </div> //Close for topLayer
      </div> //Close for container
   }
})
```

However this doesn't work out as it expects a closing div tag within the if condition. Is it possible to do something of this sort?

If there was no conditional logic, the only thing required would have been :

```
array.map((data, index) => {
   return(
      <div class="topLayer">
        <div class="container">
  
         <div><p>Displaying index {i} , data is: {array[i]}</p></div>
   
        </div> //Close for topLayer
      </div> //Close for container
   })
})
```

Comment: Please attention to if you want to change the page UI, you should use the State in the Reactjs.

Comment: Its hard to say, there's so many ways to approach this. Maybe use reduce to group your content so you have a data structure like [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].

Answer (score 0):

you have to return an element instead of just adding the div tag you need to do `return <div></div>` in each if block and a default one if all conditions fails - alternatively you could use a ternary operator in that case you don't need to use the return statement

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you are trying to add a new block or something. Try like below which will give an idea.

```
export default function App() {
  const arrayData = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {arrayData.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <div class="topLayer">
            <div class="container">
              <div>
                <p>
                  Displaying index {index} , data is: {arrayData[index]}
                </p>
                {(index + 1) % 3 === 0 ? <br /> : undefined}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Where a `break-line` will be added after every 3 chunks of data.